# Can a Blank Node have rdf:type property?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, blank-nodes

Is it valid to form the following triple:

```
_:bn rdf:type foaf:name
```

where `_:bn` is a blank node?

I read the W3C standards for [`rdf:type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-schema-20040210/#ch_type). It says that the [`rdfs:domain`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-schema-20040210/#ch_domain) of `rdf:type` is [`rdfs:resource`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-schema-20040210/#ch_resource). `rdfs:resource` is the the class of everything.

So is it correct to assign a `rdf:type` for a blank node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely fine. Blank nodes are simply things without a URL identifier. (Well it's a little more complex, but I wouldn't worry about it)

Like a car without a registration plate, it doesn't stop them doing anything cars with plates can do.

But it makes life difficult for people trying to work out whether they've seen the same car, or find the car.

Comment: I really like the analogy :)

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic answer, a blank node is a purely abstract "thing" being provided by a graph database.

Giving a type to a node means creating a triple, in other words providing a property to a subject.

```
subject= my blank node
property=rdf:type 
object=foaf:name
```

A blank node might not have an identifier but starts being a concrete "thing" when it becomes the subject of properties.

The absence of an identifier is not definitely a problem for considering the node to be a resource as it might later be associated to the node via another triple. e.g. (using the appropriate Dublin Core property for an identifier) :

```
subject= my blank node
property=http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject
object=http://my-testdomain.com/my-url
```